# Changing how the ui-view directive handles page transitions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

**Edit: DON'T DO THIS.** It's a waste of time unless you want to spend hours debugging, turns out this is a lot more complicated than I first thought. For now the solution to this is:

- Move the loading of resources out of the resolvers and into the controller.
- Remove all enter animations handled by ui-router.
- Add your own animation init and enter classes to the main scope with ng-class.
- Use `$scope.$emit` from the page-specific controllers to tell the main controller when the stuff has finished loading.

In short, if you need this (I have seen a few questions on the ui-router issue tracker) don't use resolvers or ng-animate for the enter animations. You also can't do it on the `$stateChangeStart` event and the leaving animations as this collides with how ui-router works.

Below is my original question.

---

I have a specific use case where I need the page transitions and resolves to happen in a certain order currently they happen like this:

```
resolve > animate out > animate in
```

I need it more like this:

```
animate out > resolve > animate in
```

I decided to check out the ui-router source code and find out why it behaves they way it does. Fortunately it's a very simple mod. In the ui-view directive we have this code.

```
scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
    updateView(false); // cleanupLastView(); is at the end of this function
});
scope.$on('$viewContentLoading', function() {
    updateView(false); // cleanupLastView(); is at the end of this function
});
```

I need to updated it to:

```
scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
    cleanupLastView();
});
scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
    updateView(false); // remove cleanupLastView();
});
scope.$on('$viewContentLoading', function() {
    updateView(false); // remove cleanupLastView();
});
```

The problem is that for obvious reasons, I don't want to go and hack the core. Is there any way to "de-register" the `ui-router`'s `ui-view` directive and tell it to use one of mine instead?

Comment: Hi ! Finally how did you achieve this ? I'm pretty new with angular and I try to achieve the same result as you. Some example code to provide ? :3

Comment: I've written up the answer below. I can't provide code but it's pretty simple. Just use ng-class to trigger the "in" animations and only allow ng-view to trigger the "out" animations.

Even better, don't prevent the page loading at all. Make the page transition happen quickly and populate the data asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I actually wrote this question up and then found an answer. Posting it for anyone else on their travels around the internet.

The answer was to copy **BOTH** ui-view directives and simply add a new directive called (for example) `rich97-view`. Then you can use it in your view as if you were using ui-view. The great thing about this methods is that the mod only applies where you need it to, the default behavior is unchanged.